# Rails Duplicate Comment Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I create a comment in my feed, rails is duplicating all the previous comments.

Comments Contoller

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

Posts Show

```
<div class="content">
<%= markdown(@post.content) %>

<ul class="comments">
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= render @post.comments %>
<% end %>
</ul>

<%= render "comments/form" %>
</div>
```

_comment.html.erb

```
<li>
<%= link_to comment.name, comment.url, :title => "visit website", :target => "_blank", :rel => "nofollow" %>
<p><%= comment.body %></p>
<time><%= comment.created_at.utc.strftime("%m.%d.%Y") %></time>

<%= link_to 'X', [comment.post, comment],
                :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
                :method => :delete %>
</li>
```

Post.rb

```
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment.rb

```
belongs_to :post
```

After I create first comment
[image: First Comment]

After I create first comment
[image: Second Comment]

Comment: `duplicating all the previous comments.`?

Comment: Please define 'duplicates' more clearly with some of the current sample output.  Right now it looks like each time the comment is added all comments get displayed with a new empty form but I am guessing that is not what you are seeing?

Comment: I make a comment, it displays fine. I create another comment, it displays under the previous comment, then duplicates both the first and second comments under them. If I make a third comment, this displays under the first two, and under the duplicated two, then also duplicates the three comments again. Sorry, hard to explain.

Comment: Does reloading fix the issue?

Comment: Nope reloading doesn't fix it. I've added images to help explain my situation.

Comment: You're rendering all the comments in a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from your code:

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= render @post.comments %>
<% end %>
```

this should either be:

```
<%= render @post.comments %>
```

or:

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= render comment %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling what you want in your loop is this:

```
<ul class="comments">
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= render comment %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

And not render, again, the whole collection `@post.comments`